# How to configure a Panasonic 50 inch plasma screen with xorg.conf

Tags: xorg.conf

I have Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) installed on a Gigabyte Brix (GB-BACE-3150).  It is connected to a 50 inch Panasonic Plasma TV (TH-50PX600A) via HDMI.  The image on the screen is larger then the screen on all sides, cutting off the edges.  The system information for the screen reports it as a 65 inch Panasonic TV instead of a 50 inch.  I note that the EDID for the TV does not specify the display size.  It therefore seems to default to 65 inch.

I thought that if I specified the correct display size through an xorg.conf file the display would be shrunk to fit the screen, but this is not the case, the display image is still larger than the screen.

The TV does not have an aspect ratio adjustment that allows the image to be shrunk to fit.

I have reviewed the xorg log file and it seems that it is loading my xorg.conf correctly.  My xorg.conf and the log file are as follows.

Any advice on how to get the image to fit the TV screen size would be greatly appreciated.

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier    "Panasonic-50"
        HorizSync 15.0 - 46.0 
        VertRefresh 48.0 - 61.0 
        Modeline "1280x720" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1366x768" 85.500 1360 1440 1552 1792 768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1080" 74.250 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1094 1125 +hsync +vsync interlace
    DisplaySize 1106 622
        Option       "UseEDID" "false"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen 0"
        Monitor         "Panasonic-50"
        Device          "Intel Graphics"

    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1280x720" "1366x768" "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

X.Org X Server 1.19.3
Release Date: 2017-03-15
[     6.560] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     6.560] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[     6.560] Current Operating System: Linux BRICK 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018 x86_64
[     6.560] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=69b8f9c0-513a-443b-bb08-6684e58a0022 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[     6.560] Build Date: 13 October 2017  02:11:50PM
[     6.560] xorg-server 2:1.19.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[     6.560] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[     6.560]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     6.560] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     6.561] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Mar  3 20:50:09 2018
[     6.561] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     6.561] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     6.562] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     6.562] (**) |-->Screen "Screen 0" (0)
[     6.562] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Panasonic-50"
[     6.563] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[     6.563] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     6.563] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     6.563] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     6.563] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[     6.563] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     6.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     6.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     6.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[     6.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.563] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     6.563]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.563] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[     6.563] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     6.563] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     6.563] (II) Loader magic: 0x561ac385be00
[     6.563] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     6.563]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     6.563]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[     6.563]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     6.563]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     6.565] (++) using VT number 7

[     6.566] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     6.567] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     6.584] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:22b1:1458:1000 rev 33, Mem @ 0x90000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     6.584] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     6.586] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     6.599] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.600]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.600]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     6.600] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[     6.600] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     6.605] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.605]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.99.917
[     6.605]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     6.605]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[     6.605] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[     6.606] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[     6.606] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[     6.606] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[     6.607] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20170619
[     6.607] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04 2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[     6.607] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[     6.609] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics
[     6.610] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2; using a maximum of 4 threads
[     6.610] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     6.610] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     6.610] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     6.611] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 using monitor section Panasonic-50
[     6.611] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[     6.611] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Output DP2 has no monitor section
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP2
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[     6.612] (II) intel(0): Output DP3 has no monitor section
[     6.613] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP3
[     6.613] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI3 has no monitor section
[     6.613] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI3
[     6.613] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[     6.613] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[     6.613] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[     6.613] (--) intel(0): Output HDMI3 using initial mode 1280x720 on pipe 2
[     6.613] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[     6.614] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     6.614] (**) intel(0): Display dimensions: (1106, 622) mm
[     6.614] (**) intel(0): DPI set to (29, 29)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is a TV "feature" generally referred to as *overscan*. You can't fix it by changing the X settings because there is nothing wrong with them in the first place. The TV is throwing away the outer edge of the image on purpose, and it will keep doing that no matter what the input signal is.

The good news is that it can be turned off, so just have a trawl through the TV menu until you find it. (I happen to have a Panasonic plasma as well, in mine it's under Picture > Screen Settings > 16:9 Overscan, but ymmv)

Comment: Thanks Pedro,  Unfortunately the TV doesn't have the facility to turn overscan off.  I did get another PC, an Intel NUC that has a better graphics card/driver that allowed the image size to be scaled down, so all good now.